# Select multiple selected values from a column from each row

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL so please bear with me. I am trying to select rows only with specific product codes. When I run it for one selection without OR statement in the below query results are fine but as soon I add another choice with OR statement the results are not accurate. It looks like it keeps putting ProductCode MW-BShorts-0009 against each OrderID.

```
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID, OrderDetails.ProductCode
FROM 
    Orders, OrderDetails
WHERE 
    Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
    AND OrderDetails.ProductCode = 'MacFRC'
    OR OrderDetails.ProductCode = 'MW-BShorts-0009'
```

Comment: Please add your rdbms.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) clause and its better to use [Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) instead of [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join)

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, OrderDetails.ProductCode
FROM Orders 
JOIN OrderDetails
ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
AND OrderDetails.ProductCode IN ('MacFRC','MW-BShorts-0009')
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i was looking for :) Love you man. Thanks!!

Comment: Does he really need a join to the Orders table? I think OrderId on the OrderDetails table should be a foreign key to the OrderId in the orders table and therefore he does not need a join IMO.

Comment: Your are welcome. As @ankk has mentioned if this itself is the query then no need of a join. If this is a part of the bigger query or other columns are involved then the join is valid

Comment: yeah exactly you got me right. there are a few more columns involved in the query but I didn't mention them earlier not to make it too complicated. You got me exactly what I was looking for. Much appriciated

Comment: @AZee Please consider accepting this or other answers to let the community know that your question has been solved. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

From your above query it looks like you dont even need a join or select from the Orders table

```
select OrderID, ProductCode
from OrderDetails
where ProductCode IN ('MacFRC','MW-BShorts-0009')
```

Answer (score 1):

`AND` has precedence over `OR` so you'd need to enclose the `OR` clause in parentheses:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, OrderDetails.ProductCode
FROM Orders, OrderDetails
WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
AND 
    (OrderDetails.ProductCode = 'MacFRC'
     OR OrderDetails.ProductCode = 'MW-BShorts-0009')
```

However you should use a `JOIN` clause instead of adding a `WHERE` condition to match the tables ,  and can use `IN` instead of `OR`ing two conditions:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, OrderDetails.ProductCode
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN OrderDetails
  ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
WHERE OrderDetails.ProductCode IN ('MacFRC', 'MW-BShorts-0009')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IN as Srikanth has mentioned.  But you need to understand the concept of [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) as well.  In your case, you are saying "Either Orders.OrderID must equal OrderDetails.OrderID and OrderDetails.ProductCode must equal 'MacFRC', or OrderDetails.ProductCode must equal 'MW-BShorts-0009'."  What you want is for the OrderID = ProductCode criterion to apply to either ProductCode.

All you need to do is override the default precedence with parentheses, same as you would if you want to do an addition before a multiplication.  Like this:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, OrderDetails.ProductCode
FROM Orders, OrderDetails
WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
AND (OrderDetails.ProductCode = 'MacFRC'
OR OrderDetails.ProductCode = 'MW-BShorts-0009')
```